# What are VRFs how they are used and how to configure them?

Tags: routing, switching

Some one explain what is a VRF and how they are used and why they are used.

Comment: Really a simple search would have turned up many explanations is less time than it took you to ask here.

Comment: @RonMaupin did that though but still unclear about the whole concept of using them ( i'm in a beginner stage in learning networking concepts)..thought that any one here could have used them real time might explain clearly.

Comment: If you're a beginner, it's best to learn basic routing concepts first.  VRFs are a more advanced idea.  Once you understand basics, the "why" will make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like a VLAN is a virtual instance of a Layer 2 broadcast segment, which allows the existence of multiple broadcast domains on one physical device.
Switches by default associate VLAN 1 to all its ports, so all attached users can broadcast each other.

Likewise a VRF is a virtual instance of a Layer 3 routing domain, which allows the existence of multiple routing instances on the same physical device.
Routers by default associate VRF default to all its ports, so traffic can be routed between all ports.